# When I register any user but remember_token() Always Null In Db During Insertion

Tags: laravel

I am trying to register any user but remember_token() Always Null In Db During Insertion ,

It success but remember_token is missing

How to fix it ?

**Database**

user table
[image]

**controller**

```
public function registeraction(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name'     => 'Required',
        'email'    => 'Required',
        'password' => 'Required',
    ]);
    $user = User::create(request(['name', 'email', 'password']));
    $name = $request->input('name');
    $email = $request->input('email');
    $password = $request->input('password');

    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
        // Authentication passed...
        return redirect()->to('/');
    }
}
```

**html view**

```
<form action="{{route('register.action')}}" method="post">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Email address</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control " placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-12">Register</button>
</form>
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('Register','CheckController@register');
Route::post('Register/action','CheckController@registeraction')->name('register.action');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's OK for `remember_token` to be `null` when you register a new user, because it will be set when the user checks "Remember me" checkbox of login page when logging-in.

But you can manually set this if needed:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

$user->setRememberToken(Str::random(60));
$user->save();
```